# Trying to figure out what this hash function returns

Tags: c++, hash

I'm starting to learn about hash functions, and I came across this one.  It takes in a string and only does something with the first character, but I'm not sure what it returns. I believe is subtracts the ASCII value of A from the first char and returns that as an int for use as the key, but I'm not sure.  Is this right? Here is the code.

```
int f(string s){return s[0]-'a';}
```

Comment: It returns the *platform-dependent* value of `'a'` subtracted from the first character of the string. ASCII may be true on your platform, but [it is a bit presumptuous to claim universally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC). It is also a dreadful hash function if the final value from this is used as the bucket index, as it guarantees all strings starting with the same character will collide with each other.

Comment: This is the first hash function that I have seen that could return a negative value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will substract the value of `a` from the first character of the string `s`

This is a very bad example of a hash function! 
Every string that start with the same character will collides